# ADF Event Based Trigger not working (when file is being moved via java code)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using Azure Data Factory where I have configured an event-based trigger pointing to **ADLS Gen 2 storage**.

The trigger expects a file to end with **Completed-DS001_01.csv ("Blob Path Ends With")** in the file location specified in **"Blob Path Begins With"**.

When a file (having filename as Completed-DS001_01.csv) is **manually uploaded** or moved via pipeline or logic app to the specified folder location, the trigger is working as expected but when the same file is being placed by **some java API** the **trigger is not working**.

I have tried with(in Java service):

1. `azcopy copy` service to upload the file called via a shell/batch script.
2. Storage API (**Cloudblockblob**) to get the blob reference and used `blob.upload()` utility.

Comment: Is the issue solved now? Does the java code removed the source file? As I know, it just copy the file/content to another path.  If the source files are still exist,  no changes for the files and of course the event trigger not works.

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, replying on her behalf since we are working together on this, the data source & data sink are at different storage accounts. The event grid trigger has been applied to the data sink where there was no file present & java code uploads the file.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem happens when you are using some Microsoft utility to transfer files like in this case it's `azcopy` which has been run using a bash script in the java application like `azcopy copy %1(source) %2(destination) --recursive` .

For triggers listening in ADLS using microservices to activate, the file stream needs to be uploaded using some azure packages which are available as maven dependencies.

The dependency that can be used to resolve this issue is: `https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-file-datalake -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
    <version>12.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After this, clients need to be created in the order:

```
DataLakeServiceCleient -> DataLakeFileSystemClient -> DataLakeDirectoryClient -> DataLakeFileClient
```

Then create a file using FileClient, create a buffered input stream of the file that needs to be uploaded.

Finally use, `fileClient.append(stream,0,fileSize)` or `fileClient.upload(filePath,true)` and flush the stream using `fileClient.flush(fileSize)`

This will activate the trigger on file upload.